# What do you call someone who hates Christmas?

Tags: single-word-requests

Anything other than Scrooge, please.

Comment: Female or male? Atheist or agnostic? Monster or child? Fictional or real? Funny or serious. Pejorative or neutral? Your question lacks detail.

Comment: Sorry to be a Scrooge, but there *is* no other term than "Scrooge".  Except perhaps its synonyms -- did you check those?

Comment: @HotLicks I wouldn't say that *christougenniatikophobic* was quite the synonym that, say, *grinch* was, since it's more sympathetic. It does though imply an irrational quality (though one can of course widen *-phobia* beyond the psychiatric meaning of an irrational fear) leaving no term I can think of for someone who has a sound reason for disliking the holiday but without the attack upon others' enjoyment of the holiday that *scrooge* and *grinch* suggest.

Comment: Christmas-hater

Answer (score 4):

Though Scrooge-*related*, you could call someone who hates Christmas a humbug. Or a Grinch.